# Easiest way to check if continuous subform recordset was changed by the user?

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset, subform

I am creating a Microsoft Access 2010 application that records errors made in a separate workflow system. The user enters a workflow number, clicks search, and a continuous subform appears below with as many rows as there are people who have touched that workflow in the other system. The continuous subform is also populated with rows for errors that were previously logged.

The user then checkmarks a box on each of those rows to indicate that those particular people made an error. The user then enters a description of the error, etc.

If the user interacts with a previously logged error row, I want to know it so that I can go back and update/delete that previous error.

I'm able to use VBA to retrieve the RecordSet of the continuous subform. However, I don't see a property/method on that subform recordset that would allow me to check to see if the user actually touched one of the fields on that row of the continuous subform.

Other than comparing the row in the subform recordset with the row in the database field by field to see if something changed, is there a way in VBA to just check to see if a row on a subform recordset was changed after being presented to the user?

Comment: look at the `AfterUpdate` event on your subform. It will fire after a user makes a change to a record. You can then use that record reference to do whatever.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Form.Dirty to checkif something was changed....

I have a similiar situation  and i solved this way...

1 - When i open a form with a subform...

2 - Create a clone recordset of original records of subforms

3- And then check if user change or not something in the form or in subform using [dirty].

4 - If something was changed and dirty was true in the form or subform you can disabled buttons (next, new...) from main form and only permit save and undo changes actions

5 - if user saves, we just update records in main table and recreate the clone recordset with new values

6 - if user click UNDO button, then we make compare and copy the records from clone recordset/table to original table

### I think you can find a working sample using DAO here: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/131535

heres a simple function code you can use to copy all records from subform to another temporary table/recorset (eg:TDetPedTemp) and then reverting the process copy back to original if necessary;

```
// copy actual subforms records to a temporary new table/recordset
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rs As ADODB.Recordset
Dim rs2 As ADODB.Recordset

Set cnn = CurrentProject.Connection
Set rs = New ADODB.Recordset
Set rs2 = New ADODB.Recordset

'open main recordset (TDetPed)
rs.Open "SELECT TDetPed.* FROM TDetPed WHERE CodPed = " & CodPed & "", cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic


'open clone table recordset (TDetPedTemp)
rs2.Open "TDetPedTemp", cnn, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic

'move to first record of main table
rs.MoveFirst

'add record by record in clone table(rs2) from maintable(rs)
Do Until rs.EOF
rs2.AddNew
rs2("CodPed") = rs("CodPed")
rs2("CodDetPed") = rs("CodDetPed")
rs2("CodInterno") = rs("CodInterno")
rs2("DescrDetPed") = rs("DescrDetPed")
rs2("DescontoDetPed") = rs("DescontoDetPed")
rs2("CodProd") = rs("CodProd")
rs2("PreçoDetPed") = rs("PreçoDetPed")
rs2("QtdeDetPed") = rs("QtdeDetPed")

'update current added record in clone table
rs2.Update

'move to next record in main table
rs.MoveNext
'Move para o proximo registro do detalhe do pedido
Loop

'close everthing
rs.Close
rs2.Close
cnn.Close
'clean everthing
Set rs = Nothing
Set rs2 = Nothing
Set cnn = Nothing
```

And to undo the changes the code was the same, just the sources order is diferent. WE just need to first delete the original records from table (eg:TDetPed) and then copy temporary new records (eg: TDetPedTemp) to original recorset

```
'del original files
cnn.Execute "Delete * FROM TDetPed WHERE CodPed = " & CodPed & ""
```